# Representar String en forma numérica en R

Tags: r, rstudio, machine-learning, redes-neuronales

Me gustaría saber si en R existe alguna forma de convertir un vector o dataframe que contenga texto a alguna representación numérica que me sirva luego para meterla a una red neuronal. Por ejemplo:

```
c("1", "hola", "2017-02-01", "pepito")
```

a esto (son valores aleatorios)

```
c("1", "5646", "6546666", "754.45")
```

Saludos!

Comment: No entiendo el sentido de hacer esto, como requerimiento es algo raro, encima valores aleatorios? que pueden llegar eventualmente a colisionar entre ellos. ¿Podrías explicar un poco más lo que estarías buscando) Si lo que quieres es "ocultar" la información, me parece que lo mejor es trabajar estos datos como un `factor` para luego usar el valor numérico de estos.

Comment: Lo que deseo es que sean valores "representantivos" de un string. No busco esconder nada, sólo poder meter la data a una red neuronal para predecir y estas como tienen formulas matemáticas no permiten texto.

Comment: Lo de aleatorio, me referia a que es un ejemplo, no a que quiero que sea asi. Pienso en por ejemplo: Lunes=1, Martes=2, Miercoles=3... pero que lo haga automáticamente, sin tener que yo darle el valor a cada palabra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de transformar un vector de caracteres, o una columna/variable de un `data.frame` en un vector numérico, sería apoyarse en un dato `factor`. Ejemplo:

```
x <- c("1", "hola", "2017-02-01", "pepito", "1")
as.numeric(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
[1] 1 2 3 4 1
```

Comentarios:

- Puedes verificar que le valor `"1"` que repetí al final a modo de demostración, se "mapea" siempre con el mismo valor numérico.
- Es probable que los algoritmos de redes neuronales que estés usando ya interpreten los datos de tipo `factor`, por lo que posiblemente NO necesites pasarlo a un valor numérico, simplemente transforma tus datos en un factor: `variable <- factor(variable)` o `variable <- factor(variable, level=unique(variable))` si te importa el orden natural que tiene el vector.
- Cuidado, si tu idea es ir a un modelo de aprendizaje con refuerzo, cualquier valor nuevo en estas columnas tiene que tener un nuevo `id`
- Transformar el valor de una cadena en un número, no te independiza de la cadena. Siempre vas a necesitar los valores originales para saber que el índice `4` corresponde a `pepito`

En el caso que busques transformar múltiples columnas pero que todas compartan la misma codificación deberías en primer lugar obtener los valores únicos pero del `data.frame` completo o de una selección de columnas, y con esa lista, armar las variables `factor`. Suponiendo algo así:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(c("1", "hola", "pepito", "1"), 10, replace=TRUE),
                 col2 = sample(c("1", "hola", "2017-02-01", "pepito", "1", "xx"), 10, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df

     col1       col2
1    hola       hola
2    hola       hola
3  pepito          1
4       1 2017-02-01
5       1          1
6       1 2017-02-01
7       1          1
8  pepito         xx
9  pepito 2017-02-01
10      1          1
```

Primero obtenemos los valores únicos de todo el `data.frame`

```
valores_unicos <- unique(as.vector(t(df)))
valores_unicos

[1] "hola"       "pepito"     "1"          "2017-02-01"
[5] "xx"
```

Y ahora "recodificamos" cada columna

```
apply(df, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) {as.numeric(factor(x, levels = valores_unicos))})

      col1 col2
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    1
 [3,]    2    3
 [4,]    3    4
 [5,]    3    3
 [6,]    3    4
 [7,]    3    3
 [8,]    2    5
 [9,]    2    4
[10,]    3    3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. Sólo me cabe una duda. Si hago esto a un dataframe completo, y la palabra "pepito" se repite dentro de varias observaciones, siempre me va a reconocer a "pepito" bajo el indice 4?

Comment: No, el `factor` trabaja a partir de un `vector` no de un `data.frame`, además agrega más complejidad el hecho que quieras que que el valor numérico sea consistente entre todas las columnas. Agregué una forma de hacerlo en mi última edición.